# How to edit source code passwd.c on Yocto project and rebuild it

Tags: passwords, yocto

I am new to Yocto, I learn yocto about half years ago. Following is the situation:

- Yocto target machine: intel corei7-64
- Socket server and client communicated with Rabbit encrypted password.
- Socket client can change the password.
- User can use ssh to login to the corei7 Yocto embedded Machine.
- User can use `passwd` to change the password.

After googling, I think maybe I need to change the source code passwd.c and read the password user typed in and save the password to somewhere and use the algorithm to read/write/encrypt/decrypt for the Socket server to use.

```
$ find . -name passwd.c
./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/shadow/4.2.1-r0/license-destdir/shadow/passwd.c
./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/shadow/4.2.1-r0/packages-split/shadow-dbg/usr/src/debug/shadow/4.2.1-r0/shadow-4.2.1/src/passwd.c
./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/shadow/4.2.1-r0/shadow-4.2.1/src/passwd.c
./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/shadow/4.2.1-r0/package/usr/src/debug/shadow/4.2.1-r0/shadow-4.2.1/src/passwd.c
./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/busybox/1.24.1-r0/packages-split/busybox-dbg/usr/src/debug/busybox/1.24.1-r0/busybox-1.24.1/loginutils/passwd.c
./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/busybox/1.24.1-r0/busybox-1.24.1/loginutils/passwd.c
./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/busybox/1.24.1-r0/package/usr/src/debug/busybox/1.24.1-r0/busybox-1.24.1/loginutils/passwd.c
./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/openssl/1.0.2h-r0/packages-split/openssl-dbg/usr/src/debug/openssl/1.0.2h-r0/openssl-1.0.2h/apps/passwd.c
./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/openssl/1.0.2h-r0/openssl-1.0.2h/apps/passwd.c
./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/openssl/1.0.2h-r0/package/usr/src/debug/openssl/1.0.2h-r0/openssl-1.0.2h/apps/passwd.c
./build/tmp/deploy/licenses/shadow/passwd.c
./build/tmp/deploy/licenses/shadow-native/passwd.c
```

Because I am not sure which one the build will be used, I added some tag in each passwd.c, and rebuild the image by following command.

```
$ bitbake -f -c compile busybox
$ bitbake -f -c compile linux-yocto
$ bitbake -f -c deploy linux-yocto
$ bitbake core-image-minimal
```

But after login to the new build, I can not find any change? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

Please check whether package shadow is installed. If yes, command passwd  is used from package shadow. Otherwise use the one from busybox. You could do_patch for the package(shadow or busybox). And then make some modification. After build and verification that the modification works, add the patch to SRC_URI.

For shadow, the source file is in
./build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/shadow/4.2.1-r0/shadow-4.2.1/